Why did Emily get so sick when she found out the title of the poem?
In Dickinson S01E07, Emily gets so sick when she hears that Austin threw a title there in the poem. (Timestamp 18:39)

Austin Dickinson: Oh, and you forgot to read the title.
Emily Dickinson: Title ?
Austin Dickinson: Yeah, I threw one on there.
Mrs. Dickinson: "To Mrs. Blank. With a rose."

Why did Emily get so shocked? She wanted her poem to be published, which has been done. However, she gets sick at this title. Why is that so?

Does she actually get sick or just say it? It's a fairly common phrase to indicate that one does not like something. Especially as he changed the title of Emily's poem from ""Nobody knows this little Rose"

My point of using the word "sick" is "upset". Emily said - "Excuse me, I feel sick". That's why i continued using that word.

This is missing a LOT of context.
First of all, the scene is Emily with her family at the table. They are discussing her brother Austin's poem, which just won the town's poetry contest. However, the true author of the poem was titular character Emily Dickinson (based off of the historical poet), and she asked Austin to submit it under his own name in order to avoid angering her father. So importantly, only Austin and Emily know that Emily wrote the poem. It's unclear to me whether that bothers her, since she did earlier convince him to agree to it as well as explicitly saying she would be fine with her brother getting the credit. But there's more to it!
The poem in question, read aloud in its entirety just moments earlier, is:

Nobody knows this little Rose —
It might a pilgrim be
Did I not take it from the ways
And lift it up to thee.
Only a Bee will miss it —
Only a Butterfly,
Hastening from far journey —
On its breast to lie —
Only a Bird will wonder —
Only a Breeze will sigh —
Ah Little Rose — how easy
For such as thee to die!

This is a real-life poem of Dickinson's titled "Nobody knows this little Rose". I am not a poetry analyst by trade, but I would suggest that the poem is about a rose (a perfect being) being taken away from its way (its natural environment) and thus not being missed by anyone: "Only a Bird will wonder / Only a Breeze will sigh". The last line in particular laments how easy it is for the rose to die, suggesting Dickinson is commenting on the fragility of flawlessness (you don't have to agree with me though, the exact true meaning isn't necessary to answer this question).
However, Emily had not given Austin her title for the poem, so when Austin submitted it, he wrote one himself. In the quote, Austin says he named it "To Mrs. Blank. With a rose". It's clear from this title that Austin thought the poem was a love poem! Austin, not being much of a poet himself, probably saw that on the surface level, the poem mentions giving someone a rose, which led him to incorrectly conclude that a romantic title would be appropriate.
Finally, not knowing the true theme of the poem, Austin has to bluff to his family à la Balderdash/Fictionary. A few moments earlier, Austin had said to the table that he wrote it for Sue. Austin is engaged to be married to Sue; however, crucially, Emily and Sue are secretly in love with each other under the guise of being best friends (keep in mind, this series is set in 1800s America).

So, Emily has three very strong reasons to react to Austin's title with disgust:

Emily has to sit there while her family praises Austin for her work.

Emily is appalled that Austin has wholly misinterpreted her poem and given it an incongruent title.

Not only has Austin misidentified it as a love poem, he unknowingly dedicated it to Emily's secret lover.


All of these three reasons materialize during this scene, which is why Emily says "Excuse me, I feel sick". As a bonus, note that Emily is speaking with a double meaning here.  To her family, this remark probably just seems like Emily reacting with exaggerated disgust to her brother's sappy love poem, which is a common brother/sister trope.
